# PHP - Remove all content inside <script> and CDATA of HTML string

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, domdocument

I should remove all content (and tags) between  tags in a PHP string fetched from file_get_contents of a generic website URL.
I'm using the RegEx expression:

```
preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $string);
```

It works fine, but my problem is that, if a script contains the CDATA tag, it won't work. An example of string would be:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var variable = {"ajax":"....."}
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

I guess that the problem is with those "/*" and "*/" tags.

---

I've already searched on google and on Stack Overflow, but ther is no question with that particular type of cdata tag (with /* and */), so nothing works.
Any suggestion?
**Edit:**
As Steve answered, i am now using a code like this:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('script') as $scripttag){
$scripttag->parentNode->removeChild($scripttag);
}
```

And then i have:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('ins') as $string) {
    $string2 .= $string->nodeValue;
    $string2 .= ' ';
}
```

But that returns a $string2 with script tags inside.

**EDIT 2 (SOLVED):**
With Steve's help, I found out that using Xpath solves the problem:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//script') as $node) {
   $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

That removes script tags also inside another tag, for example:

```
<ins><script>First JS</script></ins>
<ins>Hello</ins>
<script>Second JS</script>
```

Will output

```
Hello
```

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: regex for html parsing isn't a good idea. And don't forget to remove <img onload="hack();" />

Comment: What is the problem? I see it works ["nicely"](https://regex101.com/r/kS2oB7/1) (of course, with the provided example only).

Comment: @stribizhev that is the problem parsing html with regex, as from an attacker view, i don't follow the rules.... https://regex101.com/r/zV1yA2/1

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advices, but as i answered to Steve, i'm using also a DOMDocument, but don't know if it is possible to re-use it after deleting content...

Comment: then please update your question ``[...] I'm using the RegEx expression [...]`` - i don't suggest to use libaries but you should look at the ``htmlpurifier`` lib.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but I'm using the DOMDocument for fetching the html and then preg_replace for replacing the content. My problem is that if i use DOM for removing scripts, it won't work, it keeps the scripts in...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use regex for this, use a proper html parser like domdocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html);
//removing elements from a nodelist resets the internal pointer, so traverse backwards:
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');
$count = $elements->length;
while(--$count){
    $elements->item($count)->parentNode->removeChild($elements->item($count));
}

//you can do further dom manipulation here if needed
$insertContents='';
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('ins') as $insert){
    $insertContents .= $insert->nodeValue . ' ';
}
//if you need the complete html at all:
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
//your desired string:
echo $insertContents;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but i already use the DOMDocument for a $dom->getElementsByTagName('ins');

Is it possible to use another function instead of $dom->saveHTML(); to save the new dom object and re-use it for the other getElements? (sorry for my ignorance about dom)

Comment: You can just keep using the same instance - you can call `getElementsByTagName` as many times as you like and only call `saveHTML` when you havge finished processing

Comment: Hi Steve, sorry for my insistence, but if i use that code like you said, it keeps the script tags in. In particular, what i do is 
`foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('ins') as $string) {
            $string2 .= $string->nodeValue;
     $string2 .= ' ';
     }`
But that returns a $string2 with script tags again...
Sorry again for my ignorance.

Comment: @TekLitto Oops, sorry. My mistake. Turns out you need to be careful when removing elements whilst traversing them - see update

Comment: Thanks @Steve, now it works very well, but there is another little problem, if i have something like `<ins><script>First JS</script></ins><script>Second JS</script>` the echo $insertContents; will output "First JS", is it solvable?

Comment: while(--$count > -1) will remove the last in the list, too.